# Unable to set the content of the box in an appropraite way using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to material UI, i was going through few of the links and then i could built the content of the message.

Here is the Code:

```
class Data extends React.Component {


  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">S</Avatar>}
          title={
            // <TextField placeholder="Search" margin="normal" />
            <>
              <InputBase placeholder="Search Google Maps" margin="normal" />
              <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
                <SearchIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent className={classes.contentHeight} >
          <Message isSender content="Hello" />
          <Message content="Hello back" />
          <Message isSender content="Anyone there" />
          <Message content="Yes" />
          <Message isSender content="Thank you for replying" />
        </CardContent>

      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div to bottom of your Card content component and scroll to it whenever your component is updated.Check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-blackwell-hqpnt)

```
<div
    style={{ float: "left", clear: "both" }}
    ref={el => {
          this.messagesEnd = el;
    }}
/>
  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.messagesEnd.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }
```

Comment: but it is not showing the updated message and moreover getElementbyId is not a good approach so thats why i'm looking for any other method

Comment: update answer, please check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-blackwell-hqpnt) and click the button to test